# Singleton in Swift

Tags: swift, singleton

I've been trying to implement a singleton to be used as a cache for photos which I uploaded to my iOS app from the web. I've attached three variants in the code below.  I tried to get variant 2 working but it is causing a compiler error which I do not understand and would like to get help on what am I doing wrong.  Variant 1 does the caching but I do not like the use of a global variable.  Variant 3 does not do the actual caching and I believe it is because I am getting a copy in the assignment to var ic = ...., is that correct?

Any feedback and insight will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Zvi

```
import UIKit

private var imageCache: [String: UIImage?] = [String : UIImage?]()

class ImageCache {
    class var imageCache: [String : UIImage?] {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: [String : UIImage?]?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = [String : UIImage?]()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-5s/gallery/a/images/download/photo_1.jpg")!)!)

        //variant 1 - this code is working
        imageCache["photo_1"] = imageView.image
        NSLog(imageCache["photo_1"] == nil ? "no good" : "cached")

        //variant 2 - causing a compiler error on next line: '@lvalue $T7' is not identical to '(String, UIImage?)'
        //ImageCache.imageCache["photo_1"] = imageView.image
        //NSLog(ImageCache.imageCache["photo_1"] == nil ? "no good" : "cached")

        //variant 3 - not doing the caching
        //var ic = ImageCache.imageCache
        //ic["photo_1)"] = imageView.image
        //NSLog(ImageCache.imageCache["photo_1"] == nil ? "no good" : "cached")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `[String: UIImage?]` instead of `[String: UIImage]`? I think that's probably the source of the trouble you're having.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `dispatch_once` - read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26376288/148357)

Comment: just FTR, DLImageLoader is an incredible caching library, and is now in Swift.  it's priceless...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The standard singleton pattern is:

```
final class Manager {
    static let shared = Manager()

    private init() { ... }

    func foo() { ... }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
Manager.shared.foo()
```

Credit to appzYourLife for pointing out that one should declare it `final` to make sure it's not accidentally subclassed as well as the use of the `private` access modifier for the initializer, to ensure you don't accidentally instantiate another instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793747/1271826.

So, returning to your image cache question, you would use this singleton pattern:

```
final class ImageCache {

    static let shared = ImageCache()

    /// Private image cache.

    private var cache = [String: UIImage]()

    // Note, this is `private` to avoid subclassing this; singletons shouldn't be subclassed.

    private init() { }

    /// Subscript operator to retrieve and update cache

    subscript(key: String) -> UIImage? {
        get {
            return cache[key]
        }

        set (newValue) {
            cache[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
ImageCache.shared["photo1"] = image
let image2 = ImageCache.shared["photo2"])
```

Or

```
let cache = ImageCache.shared
cache["photo1"] = image
let image2 = cache["photo2"]
```

Having shown a simplistic singleton cache implementation above, we should note that you probably want to (a) make it thread safe by using `NSCache`; and (b) respond to memory pressure. So, the actual implementation is something like the following in Swift 3:

```
final class ImageCache: NSCache<AnyObject, UIImage> {

    static let shared = ImageCache()

    /// Observer for `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`.

    private var memoryWarningObserver: NSObjectProtocol!

    /// Note, this is `private` to avoid subclassing this; singletons shouldn't be subclassed.
    ///
    /// Add observer to purge cache upon memory pressure.

    private override init() {
        super.init()

        memoryWarningObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.removeAllObjects()
        }
    }

    /// The singleton will never be deallocated, but as a matter of defensive programming (in case this is
    /// later refactored to not be a singleton), let's remove the observer if deallocated.

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(memoryWarningObserver)
    }

    /// Subscript operation to retrieve and update

    subscript(key: String) -> UIImage? {
        get {
            return object(forKey: key as AnyObject)
        }

        set (newValue) {
            if let object = newValue {
                setObject(object, forKey: key as AnyObject)
            } else {
                removeObject(forKey: key as AnyObject)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And you'd use it as follows:

```
ImageCache.shared["foo"] = image
```

And

```
let image = ImageCache.shared["foo"]
```

For Swift 2.3 example, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26743597/5) of this answer.

Comment: Thanks Rob, your solution is great. Do you know if it's possible to keep them between launches? With NSUserDefaults for example? I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: @MarieDm - `NSUserDefaults` is probably not the right place for this sort of stuff. I manually write stuff to `.CachesDirectory` (from either `NSFileManager` method `URLForDirectory` or within `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`). BTW, this answer predated Swift 1.2, but I have modified it with simpler singleton pattern possible in current versions of Swift.

Comment: E.g., I would `let folder = try FileManager.default.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appending(path: "folder")` (designating my own folder within “caches”), make sure it was created (`try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true)`), and then build my file URL (`let fileURL = folder.appending(path: "filename.txt")`).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3:**

```
class SomeClass
{
    static let sharedInstance = SomeClass() 

    fileprivate override init() {
        //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer
        super.init()
    }

    func sayHello()
    { 
        print("Hello!")
    }   
}
```

Invoke some Method:

```
SomeClass.sharedInstance.sayHello() //--> "Hello"
```

Invoke some Method by creating a new class instance (fails):

```
SomeClass().sayHello() //--> 'SomeClass' cannot be constructed it has no accessible initailizers
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift-5**

To create a singleton class:

```
import UIKit

final class SharedData: NSObject {
   static let sharedInstance = SharedData()

   private override init() { }

   func methodName() { }
}
```

To access

```
let sharedClass = SharedClass.sharedInstance
```

OR

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.methodName()
```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the two different approaches to create your singleton class in swift 2.0

Approach 1) This approach is Objective C implementation over swift.

```
import UIKit

class SomeManager: NSObject {

       class var sharedInstance : SomeManager {

              struct managerStruct {

                   static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
                   static var sharedObject : SomeManager? = nil
              }

              dispatch_once(&managerStruct.onceToken) { () -> Void in
                   managerStruct.sharedObject = SomeManager()
              }
              return managerStruct.sharedObject!
       }

       func someMethod(){
              print("Some method call")
       }
 }
```

Approach 2) One line Singleton, Don't forget to implement the Private init (restrict usage of only singleton)

```
import UIKit

class SomeManager: NSObject {

       static let sharedInstance = SomeManager()

       private override init() {

       }

       func someMethod(){
            print("Some method call")
       }
  }
```

Call the Singleton method like :

```
  SomeManager.sharedInstance.someMethod()
```