# How to Create Singleton Object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I am learning about Singleton pattern in swift and efficient way to create a Singleton class and found out the best way to create as below.

```
class SingletonClass{
    static let sharedInstance = SingletonClass()
}
```

Since i have use the `let` statement it is read only property and has to be thread safe so there is no need of dispatch_once() as of Objective C.And `static`  is used to make the `sharedInstance` variable as a `class` variable i guess.

But how does this guarantee there is only one instance created throughout the application?is there a small thing i am missing?

Comment: How many copies of this class (as opposed to *objects* of this class) do you think there will be?

Comment: one copy of this class...but i may access this as SingletonClass.sharedInstance at many places...

Comment: Are you suggesting that accessing it somehow makes more copies?

Comment: more than one instance of singletonclass can be created, however sharedInstance will only be created once.

Comment: @ScottHunter   not suggesting..why it doesnot make many copies because i am creating new instance as static let sharedInstance = SingletonClass()....so what stopped me as there will be the same instance everywhere?

Comment: @WillM. how sharedInstance is created only once..in my case...?

Comment: @copeME it is a static variable that is immutable. Once it is created, it cannot be reassigned, as it was created with let. Since it is a static variable, it is associated with the class, not instances of the class.

Comment: Duplicated with question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift

Comment: nope ..its not..i am trying to know how it works too

Comment: [How to create Singleton in Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742138/singleton-in-swift/33420040#33420040)

Comment: [How to create Singleton in swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742138/singleton-in-swift/33420040#33420040)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What guarantees it is only created once is the keyword **static**. you can reference this article:
https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Hope that helps.

> The static keyword denotes that a member variable, or method, can be
>   accessed without requiring an instantiation of the class to which it
>   belongs. In simple terms, it means that you can call a method, even if
>   you've never created the object to which it belongs

Comment: you just dont declare static so that you dont need to create an object to access the variable? be more specific why to declare static in this case?

Answer (score 25):

If you want to *prevent* instantiation of your class (effectively restricting usage to only the singleton), then you mark your initializer as `private`:

```
class SingletonClass {

    static let shared = SingletonClass()

    private init() {
        // initializer code here
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am able to create a object..it doesnot give me error to create object in playground

Comment: @copeME: Private methods can only be called from within the file they were declared in.

Answer (score 5):

Make private init, for example :

```
final class Singleton {

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    //MARK: Shared Instance

    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = Singleton()

    //MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray : [String] = []

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right. And you may want to read [Files and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7) about how global and static variable are handle in Swift

Swift use this approach

> Initialize lazily, run the initializer for a global the first time it
>   is referenced, similar to Java.

It says

> it allows custom initializers, startup time in Swift scales cleanly
>   with no global initializers to slow it down, and the order of
>   execution is completely predictable.
>
> The lazy initializer for a global variable (also for static members of
>   structs and enums) is run the first time that global is accessed, and
>   is launched as `dispatch_once` to make sure that the initialization is
>   atomic. This enables a cool way to use dispatch_once in your code:
>   just declare a global variable with an initializer and mark it
>   private.