# update value of text when click back on navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have 2 controllers

and have got 1 global variable, the problem is if I go to controller 2 and click on button northAmericaClick, it will navigate back to control 1, but the value of global variable won't change!

this is my code

controller 1

```
class OurViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedServer: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedServer.setTitle(selected server, forState: UIControlState.Normal) // selected server this is global variable

}
```

controller 2

```
class selectServerController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func northAmericaClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        selectedserver = "North America"

                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Comment: If you want to set data in your parent view controller then probably you have to use unwind segue and not `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: To do same you need to use prototype method.

Comment: i know how to use segue , but this is help me because there's more than 1 input and if he go to other controller with segue the inputs will get empty

Answer (score 2):

[From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522912/passing-data-back-from-view-controllers-xcode/25523091#25523091)

You need to use a delegate. Here is an example how do use a delegate in Swift.

On your first ViewController, set your delegate when you load the second VC:

For example, if you are using the Storyboard Editor:

```
var secondViewController = (segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as  MySecondViewControllerClass)
secondViewController.delegate = self
```

Write a Protocol and define a func to write you values back

For example, create a file called "Protocol.swift" and write something like that:

```
protocol writeValueBackDelegate {
    func writeValueBack(value: String)
}
```

Add the function to your FirstViewController

```
func writeValueBack(value: String) {
   // this is my value from my second View Controller
}
```

And to your ViewControllerClass

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, writeValueBackDelegate
```

Go to the Second View Controller, and add the delegate here:

```
class SecondViewController: ViewController {

    // delegate for FirstViewController
    var delegate: writeValueBackDelegate?
```

On your Second View Controller, you can now use this to call the func in the first View Controller an pass data.

```
delegate?.writeValueBack("That is a value")
```

You also need to indicate that your first view controller implements the protocol: class ViewController: UIViewController, writeValueBackDelegate {

Comment: this is in my second controller [link](http://i.imgur.com/anvOueQ.png) ,, and this is my first controller [link](http://i.imgur.com/s31xZKf.png), when i click on select server it would go the second and show the images you it's like buttons each one got function if i click on it , it have to change the value of global variable  , i don't think i need protocol to do that ,  but thanks :)

Comment: Personally I would do it with delegate. But you also have another option. Create a Model/Data class (singleton) for you view controllers and define the variable in it. Then access to this singleton from these view controllers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742138/singleton-in-swift

Comment: Use NSUserDefault as last option.

Answer (score 0):

A part of doing it with delegate you also can create singleton class ViewControllersDataModel class and share the variable using it:

```
import Foundation

class ViewControllersDataModel {
    static let sharedInstance = ViewControllersDataModel()

    var selectedserver: String = ""

    private init() {
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
ViewControllersDataModel.sharedInstance.selectedserver = "Selected Option";
```

Comment: Property 'self.selectedserver' not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can do this with this code, only check when viewWillDisapear and call the parent of this view controller in the navicationController:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if ((self.navigationController!.viewControllers.last?.isKindOfClass(ActivityMyViewController)) == true){
        let backView:MyViewController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.last as! MyDetailViewController
        backView // do whatever you want
    }

}
```

I hope this code can help you, good luck

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for helping ;)

it was very simple

i just use then when it comeback ^^"

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    selectedServer.setTitle(selectedserv, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```