# Singleton Usage in Swift

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm still confused a little with using Swift and was hoping that someone could help clarify when and why I would you them. From my understanding of Singleton's they are single class entities, meaning that if I have Class A and I create a shared instance of Class A in a Class B its just a reference to Class A in B, so if I change or modify the object that references Class A in Class B, the original object Class is is not effected, only the object in Class B is.

What if I wanted to have a Class A, and Class B, and in Class B create a direct reference to Class A, so any changes I make are effected in class A going forward. The class is directly modified not the instance of the object that references that class.

Comment: Singleton is a pattern design where a class can be instanced only once in all your context, app etc, so your object instance is the same

Comment: A singleton is a global instance of a class that is accessible from anywhere in the application. When changes occur to that instance in one place it also changes for everything else that wants access.

Answer (score 17):

### Singleton

Look at this singleton class

```
final class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private init() { }

    var value = 0
}
```

### How does it work

There is **NO WAY** (outside of the source file where it is defined) to create more than 1 instance of this class because the initializer has been marked `private`.

The only way to access an instance of Singleton is using `sharedInstance` which does return the only instance available.

You can invoke `sharedInstance` as many times as you want, from any class and then copy it as long as you want. Every variable will always contains a reference to the **only instance** of Singleton allocated on the `Heap`.

So every change you do to `sharedInstance` will be shared everywhere.

[image]

### Example

```
let a = Singleton.sharedInstance
a.value = 1

let b = Singleton.sharedInstance
print(b.value) // 1
b.value = 2

print(a.value) // 2
```

Comment: It is imperative that the `Singleton` class be marked as `final`, otherwise we can use subclassing and to-parent casting to create several `Singleton` instances (hence invalidating the _"There is NO WAY (outside of the source file where it is defined) to create more than 1 instance ..."_ statement above), see [e.g. this example](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/e26e9cd00806c02d7a1861d2a4661a8f). Even if such workarounds are obviously bad practice, marking the `Singleton` as `final` removes the possibility of doing so.

Comment: I'd like to know about that graphic, too

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Hi, the software is [Graphic](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/graphic/id404705039?l=en&mt=12)

Comment: @appzYourLife It's pretty :) have an upboat.