# InMemory Realm Threading in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to use in memory realm to store some objects. I usually **save objects in a secondary thread** and **ask for objects on main thread**.

I also need to have a strong reference to the in memory Realm, in order to avoid data loss.

```
static private var _strongInMemoryRealm: Realm? = {
    return VideoObject._inMemoryRealm
}()

static private var _inMemoryRealm: Realm? {
    get {

        var realm: Realm? = nil

        let config = Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "InMemoryRealm")

        do {
            realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint("Realm could not be opened: ", error)
            Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
        }

        return realm

    }
}
```

I call **_inMemoryRealm** in secondary threads and **_strongInMemoryRealm** on main thread, this configuration don't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work exactly? What does it do?

Comment: I save the objects on a background thread. On the same thread with the same realm **_inMemoryRealm** i can get the objects. Back on the main thread the realm instance **_strongInMemoryRealm** return me an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I'd recommend absolutely checking to make sure your main thread Realm reference isn't being deallocated. I personally would use a [singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26743597/599344) to store the main Realm reference on the main thread. That would be the simplest reason why your Realm is staying empty.

Beyond that, when you do a write to a Realm in the background, those changes are only reflected in the main thread on the next iteration of the run loop. If you need the changes to be reflected before that, you can call `realm.refresh()` to explicitly request it to pull the latest changes.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! :)