# Singleton not working as desired

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I have a Core Data project where I'm retrieving data from multiple sources. Not all the data will be saved, so I created a struct to pass the data around before it's saved.

```
struct SearchResult {
    var myURL: String?
    var myHeadline: String?

    init() {}

    init(myURL: String, myHeadline: String) {
        self.myURL = myURL
        self.myHeadline = myHeadline
    }
}
```

Since I want to display sections in a `UITableView`, I created a `struct` for that, as well:

```
struct ResultsObjects {
    var sectionName: String?
    var sectionObjects = [SearchResult]()

    init() {}

    init(sectionName: String) {
        self.sectionName = sectionName
    }
}
```

Lastly, I created a `singleton` to keep hold `SearchResult` objects prior to saving them in the `managedObjectContext`.

```
class SearchResultsArray {
    static let sharedInstance = SearchResultsArray()
    var resultsObjectsArray = Array<ResultsObjects>()
    fileprivate init() {}
}
```

My objective is to have the `SearchResultsArray` class accessible via multiple classes and be able to dump `ResultsObjects` into it in one class and see `ResultsObjects` in another.

On `MyViewController`, I'm instantiating the `SearchResultsArray` as follows:

```
var resultsObjectsArray = SearchResultsArray.sharedInstance.resultsObjectsArray
```

I have a `UITableViewController` that I use `resultsObjectsArray` to populate.

On `MyViewController`, a button calls a method that uses a method in `MyParserClass` to parse web pages. This works, too.

`MyParserClass` declares a `resultsObjectsArray` in the same manner as `MyViewController`:

```
var resultsObjectsArray = SearchResultsArray.sharedInstance.resultsObjectsArray
```

In `MyParserClass`, a method is called that creates `SearchResult` objects, dumps them into `ResultsObjects` and appends them to `SearchResultsArray.resultsObjectsArray`. This works fine. I threw in the following line in the method that creates `ResultsObjects` that are dumped into `resultsObjectsArray`:

```
print("\(resultsObjectsArray.count) ResultsObjects in SearchResultsArray")
delegate.updateSearchResults()
```

I threw a print statement in `MyViewController`'s `updateSearchResults` delegate method and it returns 0, regardless of what `MyParserClass` says was in there just prior to calling the delegate method.

The app doesn't crash, but it seems like I've got a problem with the singleton. Any suggestions re: what I'm doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742138/singleton-in-swift

it suggests that we should both be declaring the class `final` to ensure we don't get multiples - might be worth checking out

Comment: Arrays are value types in swift. You can't use an instance variable to refer to the array. You must always use the `SearchResultsArray.sharedinstance.resultsObjectsArray`

Comment: @Paulw11 Wow! I knew I was missing something simple, but WOW! Thank you so much for your response. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: since this it is also a problem to change values inside structs - i read about a pattern named `lenses`. it is interestung. just google for `lenses swift` or this starting point https://github.com/narfdotpl/lenso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are value types in swift; when you assign an array to a variable and then assign that variable to another, the second variable refers to a copy of the original array, not the original array (technically, for efficiency, the array is copied on modify, not on assignment but the result is the same), so changes made to the original array will not be reflected in the second variable's array.

Consider

```
var someArray = [Int]()
var someOtherVariable = someArray
someArray.append(2)
```

`someArray` will contain a single value while `someOtherVariable` will still be empty.

One solution always use the `SearchResultsArray.sharedinstance.resultsObjectsArray` rather than local variable/properties.

Perhaps a better approach would be to encapsulate the array in your singleton class by providing some functions to manipulate it.  For example;

```
class SearchResultsArray {
    static let sharedInstance = SearchResultsArray()
    var resultsObjectsArray = Array<ResultsObjects>()

    public var results: [ResultsObjects] {
       get {
           return resultsObjectsArray
       }
    }


    public func add(results: ResultsObjects) {
        resultsObjectsArray.append(results)
    }


    fileprivate init() {}
}
```

Since `results` is now a read-only property and a separate `add` function exists, the class more clearly defines its semantics.

Comment: Sure, you could.  This was meant to be an example, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use a singleton in a very similar way - but I define it quite differently.

EDIT - differently, and now superseded :-(

Within the singleton `DataModelInstance` in my case, I have this

```
class DataModelInstance : NSObject, NSCoding
{
    // define all of the variables I need within the singleton

    class var sharedInstance : DataModelInstance
    {
        struct Singleton
        {
            static let instance = DataModelInstance()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    // everything else that I need in the class...
}
```

and then, in every class that needs to access it, I define a variable

```
    var dataModel = DataModelInstance.sharedInstance
```

Comment: its inside the DataModelInstance? can you add a little DataModelInstance around to make this more clear how "inside singleton" it is

Comment: ok - I have updated the answer.  I haven't included any of the NSCoding methods, or any of the data-level methods that I have implemented, but this should be enough to get a singleton working across all of my ViewControllers

Comment: @Russell: Your way of defining a Singleton is superseeded. Now you just define a singleton the way the OP did in the question.

Comment: why not this way? `class DataModelInstance : NSObject, NSCoding
{

            static let sharedInstance = DataModelInstance()

}`

Comment: yes - looks like I'm the one who has learned something today.  I have been using the same pattern in everything - since before it was superseded!

Comment: @Russell Thanks for your suggestion. Just for kicks, I tried it and I get the same result I got with my original code...the parser class sees the singleton, but when I try to access it via the delegate method on the view controller, it doesn't see what the parser did. I'm stumped. If it's not a "how I'm instantiating the singleton" issue, is it a "where I'm instantiating the singleton"?

Comment: That makes sense.  On the plus side - I have now started updating all of my projects to use the same, simpler, approach for instantiating the Singleton

Comment: just a side note: since you use a class it returns asreference - the original question uses strucs - they are used be value