# How to initiate a singleton in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class called `HTTPHelper` which is responsible for doing all my back end API requests. All methods in this class are `class` methods. As you know instance properties cannot be used from within a `class` method. I have some properties that need initialization with a `do{}catch{}` block which currently are being initiated from within an `init(){}` like so:

```
class HTTPHelper{
    init(){
        do {
            //initiate property
        } catch{}
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a mechanism similar to an `init(){}` that would initiated a static property for a singleton?

Comment: I'd suggest implementing a standard singleton (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742138/singleton-in-swift/26743597#26743597), making your properties normal instance properties of the singleton.

Comment: So basically what is happening is, you just define a class "regularly" without any `class` methods or `static` properties and just create a static instance of  the said class? @Rob

Comment: Yep. Like [`URLSession.shared`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared) or [`FileManager.default`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1409234-default)..

Comment: Thanks @Rob you've helped me a lot on here :)

Comment: +1 on the design decision of making properties **instance**, for clarity and consistency. If everything is going to be `class`/`static`, just use the class object and skip the whole `init()` thing... One or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a property to the result of a closure or function (note the `=` and `()` at the end to execute the closure—this is not the same as a computed property, where the value is re-created every time). Instead, the first time you access the property the value is lazily computed once using your function/closure and then stored in the property for future access.

```
class MyClass {
    static let myProperty: String = {
        do {
            return try blah()
        } catch {
            // error handling
        }
    }()
}
```

Of course, this is just a special case of assigning the result of a function to a property:

```
class MyClass {
    static let myProperty: String = MyClass.createMyString()

    static func createMyString() -> String {
        do {
            return try blah()
        } catch {
            // error handling
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"this is not the same as a computed property, where the value is re-created every time"_ - indeed; it is more like a **lazy** property.

Comment: Thank you Jack for you answer. If you could also incorporate Rob's comment in your post so that future readers could have access to a more complete answer I would really appreciate it.